# Debugger for unix pipe commands

Tags: shell, terminal

As I build *nix piped commands I find that I want to see the output of one stage to verify correctness before building the next stage but I don't want to re-run each stage. Does anyone know of a program that will help with that? It would keep the output of the last stage automatically to use for any new stages. I usually do this by sending the result of each command to a temporary file (i.e. tee or run each command one at a time) but it would be nice for a program to handle this.

I envision something like a tabbed interface where each tab is labeled with each pipe command and selecting a tab shows the output (at least a hundred lines) of applying that command to to the previous result.

Comment: tee requires me to do the manual work that this program should do automatically.

Answer (score 5):

Use 'tee' to copy the intermediate results out to some file as well as pass them on to the next stage of the pipe, like so:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | tee /tmp/syslog.out | grep something | tee /tmp/grep.out | sed 's/foo/bar/g' | tee /tmp/sed.out | cat >>/var/log/syslog.cleaned
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use pipes if you need bidirectional communication (i.e. with netcat):

```
mknod backpipe p
nc -l -p 80 0<backpipe | tee -a inflow | nc localhost 81 | tee -a outflow 1>backpipe
```

([via](http://clug.net.nz/index.php/netcat))

Answer (score 1):

`tee`(1) is your friend. It sends its input to both the specified file and stdout.

Stick it between your pipes. For example:

```
ls | tee /tmp/out1 | sort | tee /tmp/out2 | sed 's/foo/bar/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also the "pv" command - available in debian / ubuntu repostitories which shows you the throughput of your pipes.

An example from the man page :
Transferring a file from another process and passing the expected size to pv:

```
          cat file | pv -s 12345 | nc -w 1 somewhere.com 3000
```